# How to run AJAX operation using PHP?

Tags: php, ajax

I want to retrieve data from database using AJAX in PHP. However, it is not showing any data. I have created database connection in function `connectdb`.

HTML page to show the details:

```
  <form>
        <select name="dpd" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
        <option value="">Select a person:</option>
        <option value="1">Rohit</option>
        <option value="2">Ranbir</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#category').change(function(){
                //Retrieve Content from the back-end PHP page, and pass the ID selected
                var url = 'ajax.php?q=' + $(this).val();
                $('#txtHint').load(url);
            });
        });
</script>
```

My PHP page:

```
<?php

    connectdb();
    $q = intval($_GET['q']);
    echo "$q";
    $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '".$q."'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
     Print_r("$row");
?>
```

Comment: First of remove the single quotes `'` around `$q` in your query... It is probably an integer, right? Second, remove the double quotes `"` around `$row` in the `print_r()` statement...

Comment: @RichardBernards What do you think is wrong with double quotes in `print_r("$row")`?

Comment: @mudasobwa with `"$row"` you are doing an illegal array to string conversion...

Comment: @RichardBernards Oh, you are right, sorry.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability in this code, do not put it live. It is a good idea to switch to a library that is still maintained, such as PDO or mysqli, so you can use parameterisation.

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging with this in Firebug and check output.

After that, get only selected values.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
  print_r($row);
}
```